# «Быть под вопросом» — «стать под вопросом»

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, сказуемые

1. *Его правдивость под вопросом*.
2. *Его правдивость была под вопросом*.
3. *Его правдивость стоит под вопросом*.
4. *Его правдивость находится под вопросом*.

Перед нами СИС с грамматической связкой и именной частью, выраженной фразеологизмом «под вопросом». Всё звучит хорошо.

Но когда грамматическую связку мы меняем на полузнаменательную связку «стать» или «становиться», сказуемое начинает казаться грамматически неверным:

5. *Его правдивость стала под вопросом*.
6. *Его правдивость становилась под вопросом*.

Хочется сказать «становилась под вопрос», но это ведь фразеологизм, и он вроде как неизменяемый.

Кстати, с другими полузнаменательными связками такой проблемы нет:

7. *Его правдивость считалась под вопросом*.
8. *Его правдивость осталась под вопросом*.
9. *Его правдивость оказалась под вопросом*.

**Вопрос**

Есть ли на самом деле грамматическая некорректность со связками «стать» и «становиться»?
Если да, то в чём её причина и как её исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Формулировка *под вопросом*, в творительном падеже, описывает некоторое состояние, в котором пребывает правдивость.

Однако, формулировка *под вопрос*, в винительном падеже, описывает переход правдивости в это новое состояние, в котором она до этого не находилась.

С точки зрения согласования, тут поведение аналогично вопросам *где?* и *куда?* соответственно. В первом случае мы имеем стабильное состояние, а во втором переход в новое состояние.

Поэтому глаголы, которые указывают на переход, сочетаются с *под вопрос*; а прочие, указывающие на пребывание в состоянии, требуют *под вопросом*: вне зависимости от того, каким типом связки они являются.

Другое дело, что тут есть спорный момент, поскольку (в отличие от *ставить*) *стать* и *становиться* имеют оттенок как и начала перехода, так и завершения перехода и остановку в некотором состоянии в зависимости от контекста:

*Прежде чем меня накрыло осенним ливнем, я стал под навес.*

*Одинокий автомобиль медленно подъехал ко входу и стал под навесом.*

Тем временем, фразеологизмы почти никогда не определяются как "неизменяемые": лишь как "устойчивые". Поэтому ничто не мешает вам использовать другой глагол, просто имейте в виду, что один из синонимов куда более популярен, чем другие.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ) *Поэтому ничто не мешает вам использовать другой глагол* — дело не в изменении глагола, а в изменении формы «под вопросом» на «под вопрос». Является ли данный фразеологизм изменяемым? Мне видится, что нет: «стала/становилась под вопрос» звучит как‑то криво.

Comment: «Быть под вопросом» и «ставить под вопрос» — это два разных фразеологизма. Первый имеет значение "быть неразрешённым, невыясненным, вызывать сомнение в необходимости чего‑н.», а второй "считать сомнительным, ненужным наличие чего‑н.». Мы работаем с первым.

Comment: Я имею в виду, что нельзя менять форму слова во фразеологизме.

Answer (score 1):

В общем JKlen полностью ответил на вопрос. Я пришел к тому же, и чтобы работа не пропала зря напишу к чему.

Глаголы **быть** и **оказаться** допускают обстоятельство места, отвечающее на вопрос где:

> Я был в Германии. Я оказался в Германии. Я был под кроватью. Я
> оказался под кроватью. Я был на уроке. Я оказался на уроке.

У глагола **стать** обстоятельство места, отвечающее на вопрос где, не допускается:

> Я стал под кроватью. Я стал в Германии. Я стал на уроке.

Варианты как можно изменить ваше предложение:

> Его правдивость поставлена под вопрос/сомнение.
> Его правдивость стала быть под вопросом/сомнением. Его правдивость стала теперь под вопросом/сомнением. Его правдивость стала вопросом